# How do i add custom CSS and JS files in Sails.js 0.11?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, sails.js, meanjs

How do i add custom CSS and JS files in Sails.js 0.11 ?

Right now my tasks/pipeline.js looks like this:

```
`var tmpPath = '.tmp/public/';

var cssFilesToInject = [
  'styles/bootstrap.css',
  'styles/**/*.css'
];

var jsFilesToInject = [
  'js/dependencies/sails.io.js',
  'js/dependencies/jquery-1.11.3.min.js',
  'js/dependencies/**/*.js',
  'js/**/*.js',
];`
var templateFilesToInject = [
  'templates/**/*.html'
];
module.exports.cssFilesToInject = cssFilesToInject.map(transformPath);
module.exports.jsFilesToInject = jsFilesToInject.map(transformPath);
module.exports.templateFilesToInject = templateFilesToInject.map(transformPath);
function transformPath(path) {
  return (path.substring(0,1) == '!') ? ('!' + tmpPath + path.substring(1)) : (tmpPath + path);
}
```

My Gruntfile.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
var includeAll;
    try {
        includeAll = require('include-all');
    } catch (e0) {
        try {
            includeAll = require('sails/node_modules/include-all');
        }
        catch(e1) {
            console.error('Could not find `include-all` module.');
            console.error('Skipping grunt tasks...');
            console.error('To fix this, please run:');
            console.error('npm install include-all --save`');
            console.error();

            grunt.registerTask('default', []);
            return;
        }
    }
function loadTasks(relPath) {
        return includeAll({
            dirname: require('path').resolve(__dirname, relPath),
            filter: /(.+)\.js$/
        }) || {};
    }
function invokeConfigFn(tasks) {
        for (var taskName in tasks) {
            if (tasks.hasOwnProperty(taskName)) {
                tasks[taskName](grunt);
            }
        }
    }
var taskConfigurations = loadTasks('./tasks/config'),
        registerDefinitions = loadTasks('./tasks/register');

    // (ensure that a default task exists)
    if (!registerDefinitions.default) {
        registerDefinitions.default = function (grunt) { grunt.registerTask('default', []); };
    }

    invokeConfigFn(taskConfigurations);
    invokeConfigFn(registerDefinitions);
};
```

Path for bootstrap.css file is /api/assets/styles/bootstrap.css

Path for bootstrap.js file is /api/assests/js/bootstrap.js

Path for jquery-1.11.3.min.js is /api/assests/js/dependencies/jquery-1.11.3.min.js

importer.less files looks like this:

```
body{
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.jumbotron{
    text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron h2{
    font-size: 1.5em;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: gray;
}
```

index.ejs looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Shelfie</h1>

    <h2>Here we go!</h2>
    <a href="/user/new" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Sign up</a>
</div>
```

As you can see from the source code of the webpage given below that the bootstrap files and the jquery file has not been inserted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Shelfie</title>

    <!-- Viewport mobile tag for sensible mobile support -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


    <!--  
        Stylesheets and Preprocessors
        ==============================

        You can always bring in CSS files manually with `<link>` tags, or asynchronously
        using a solution like AMD (RequireJS).  Or, if you like, you can take advantage 
        of Sails' conventional asset pipeline (boilerplate Gruntfile).

        By default, stylesheets from your `assets/styles` folder are included
        here automatically (between STYLES and STYLES END). Both CSS (.css) and LESS (.less)
        are supported. In production, your styles will be minified and concatenated into
        a single file.

        To customize any part of the built-in behavior, just edit `tasks/pipeline.js`.
        For example, here are a few things you could do:

            + Change the order of your CSS files
            + Import stylesheets from other directories
            + Use a different or additional preprocessor, like SASS, SCSS or Stylus
    -->

    <!--STYLES-->
    <!--STYLES END-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Shelfie</h1>

        <h2>Here we go!</h2>
        <a href="/user/new" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">Sign up</a>
    </div>
</div>

    <!--
        Client-side Templates
        ========================

        HTML templates are important prerequisites of modern, rich client applications.
        To work their magic, frameworks like Backbone, Angular, Ember, and Knockout require
        that you load these templates client-side.

        By default, your Gruntfile is configured to automatically load and precompile
        client-side JST templates in your `assets/templates` folder, then
        include them here automatically (between TEMPLATES and TEMPLATES END).

        To customize this behavior to fit your needs, just edit `tasks/pipeline.js`.
        For example, here are a few things you could do:

            + Import templates from other directories
            + Use a different template engine (handlebars, jade, dust, etc.)
            + Internationalize your client-side templates using a server-side
              stringfile before they're served.
    -->

    <!--TEMPLATES-->
    <!--TEMPLATES END-->
    <!--

      Client-side Javascript
      ========================

      You can always bring in JS files manually with `script` tags, or asynchronously
      on the client using a solution like AMD (RequireJS).  Or, if you like, you can 
      take advantage of Sails' conventional asset pipeline (boilerplate Gruntfile).

      By default, files in your `assets/js` folder are included here
      automatically (between SCRIPTS and SCRIPTS END).  Both JavaScript (.js) and
      CoffeeScript (.coffee) are supported. In production, your scripts will be minified
      and concatenated into a single file.

      To customize any part of the built-in behavior, just edit `tasks/pipeline.js`.
      For example, here are a few things you could do:

          + Change the order of your scripts
          + Import scripts from other directories
          + Use a different preprocessor, like TypeScript

    -->

    <!--SCRIPTS-->
    <!--SCRIPTS END-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Comment from Shivam Saxena:  seems like your environment is not set up properly. When you start your server using sails lift, do you see any errors and if you do, please post them here.

Answer (score 1):

The js and css files are to be placed in `assets/js` and `assets/styles` folders respectively. It seems your files are in `api/assets`